# Using need and when in one sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

Is this a correct English sentence ?

> You need medicine when you sick.

I don't think it is correct because I never seen the sentence like that (need and when in one sentence) before, and today, I see this sentence in my daughter’s work book.

Comment: Hello Rifki.  Please help by answering two questions.  1) Do you think the answer is "Yes" or "No".  2) If you think the answer is "No", which part do you think might be wrong?

Comment: No, because i never seen the sentence like that (need and when in one sentence) before, and today, i see this sentence in my daughter’s work book

Comment: You can certainly say *You need medicine when **you are** sick*, but if you're going to "delete" those highlighted words, you have to discard ***both*** - giving the perfectly valid alternative ***You need medicine when sick***.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a correct sentence.  But there is no problem with "need" and "when" in the same sentence.

The word "sick" is an adjective and a noun.  It is not a verb.

You can't say "when you sick".

You say (for example)  "You need medicine when you are sick".